# LaTeX with Python 3.7 and Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I just installed Python 3.7.1 and ran the following script:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots(); frame = plt.gca()
x = np.linspace(0,2*np.pi,500)
y = np.sin(x)
ax.set_xticks(np.array([0,np.pi,2*np.pi]))
ax.set_yticks(np.array([-1,0,1]))
frame.set_xticklabels(['$0$', '$\pi$', '$2\pi$'], fontsize=20)
frame.set_yticklabels(['$-1$', '$0$', '$1$'], fontsize=20)
ax.plot(x, y)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Back in Python 2.7, the x and y tick labels would show up in LaTeX form as I wanted. Now they default to a much less pretty font, and I can't figure out how to show them in LaTeX font. Do I need to install an newer version of matplotlib?

Comment: I turned the set_xticklabels line to: `frame.set_xticklabels(['$0$', '$\pi$', '$2\pi$'], fontsize=20, usetex=True)`. This does produce the LaTeX, but I don't like how the graph looks--the labels are less bold than they were before, and the tick marks are now on the outside and not the inside of the plot.

Comment: The ticks moving from the inside of the plot to the outside by default was done in `matplotlib v2.0`: https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html#ticks That link shows how to revert to the previous behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [tmdavison's link](https://matplotlib.org/users/dflt_style_changes.html) I was able to figure it out. All I need to do is add the following lines of code:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.style.use('classic')
```

Then Matplotlib will default back to the classic style.